# how to register and use a hook in c++?

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I need to construct an AODV network that exchanges UDP packets. One of its hosts should be able to replay the packet it receives, so I'm modifying `udpBasicApp.cc` in `omnet++` inet framework. I'm trying to refer to a particular host inside the class `udpBasicApp` to specify a certain behavior for host[3] when it receives a packet. 
e.g.:

```
if(host->getIndex()== 3)
{ //replay the received packet }
```

Apparently, I cannot refer to any element of my network in the previous simple matter. There's no function inside `udpBasicApp.cc` that can get the index of the current host. I was advised to use hook mechanism to be able to access the index of the current host using the application: `udpBasicApp` How to do this using hook mechanism?

Second related question, If I cannot refer to the host index inside `udpBasicApp.cc`, how can I compare the IP address of the current host at least to the IP address I'm trying to refer to?

```
IPXAddress srcAddr;
if (srcAddr=="host[3]")
```

is not comparable as the error shows.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, you may want to provide more context

Comment: Shaika, that could become an interesting question, but a no-so-little more verbosity is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.To obtain the index of a `StandardHost` from vector you should refer to the parent module of `udpApp`:

```
if (getParentModule()->getIndex() == 3) {
// ...
}
```

2.The IPv4 address of current host may be obtained using `L3AddressResolver` class:

```
#include "inet/networklayer/common/L3AddressResolver.h"

// ...
L3Address layer3addr = L3AddressResolver().addressOf(getParentModule(),
             L3AddressResolver::ADDR_IPv4);
IPv4Address ownaddr = layer3addr.toIPv4();
```